# How to specify the types of the mongodb shell types in a script file?

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongodb-shell

I'm writing some scripts for my mongodb, they should be run just with the server, to create users and other stuff. However, I find myself constantly moving between the editor and the mongodb documentation to know what does what.

I'm using VSCode, that is powered by the Typescript server, so I usually just type something and start looking around for what I need, and help myself with the docs in the functions them self, to know what I can or can't do.